# create a YYYY-MM-DD Daterange in JScript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, date, formatting

I need no generate a full daterange in JScript from a given Startdate to now.

```
Startdate: 2010-03-25
2010-03-26
2010-03-27
...
2010-05-30
```

I am very confused with Javascript Date.

best would be a function to give a daterange as params and getting an Array of the formatted date back, something like that:

```
range[0] = 2010-03-25
range[1] = 2010-03-26
range[2] = 2010-03-27
    ...
range[x] = 2010-05-30
```

I am so confused thanks for any hint
marcus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet will store the dates as strings in the format you want in the `dateStrings` array:

```
var startDate = new Date(2010, 03, 25);
var endDate = new Date(2010, 04, 02);

var newDate = startDate;
var dateStrings = new Array()

while (newDate <= endDate){
  str = newDate.getFullYear() + "-" +
        (newDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" +
      newDate.getDate();         
  dateStrings.push(str);
  newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate()+1);
}
```

If you want to keep the date objects in an array, and format the strings yourself at a later date (pun intended), do something like the following:

```
var startDate = new Date(2010, 03, 25);
var endDate = new Date(2010, 04, 02);

var newDate = startDate;
var range = new Array()

while (newDate <= endDate){
  range.push(new Date(newDate));
  newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate()+1);
}
```

Comment: I like the second solution because you can use a map from Date to String to get the final result (https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/Map). And I'll take any excuse I can get to use map or filter or zip or foldl :-D.

Comment: awesome! thank you so much. I first thought I need to calculate with milliseconds and stuff.
many many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this. This function should return a string array of the type you requested. I copy the date to keep my function from having any side effect.

```
function getDateRange(startDate) {
    var theDate = new Date(startDate.getTime());
    var range = [];
    var now = new Date();

    while(theDate.getTime() < now.getTime()) {
        var string = theDate.getFullYear() + "-" +
                     (theDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" +
                     theDate.getDate();
        range.push(string);
        theDate.setTime(theDate.getTime() + 86400000);
    }

    return range;
}
```

#### References

[Date - MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date)